# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app). ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem, do you have any solutions?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BebQD.png)
my env
[env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWU2C.png)
I don't understand where the problem comes from, before doing the search bar everything works fine now nothing. even when removing it still the same problem
[firebase config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GSiC.png)
[mySearchbar compoment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnriG.png)
THANKS

I just want the problem to be resolved and to return to normal, I checked several times if it was the right key and it is.